# How to handle custom delegate inside NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am working on a custom request handler which contains `NSURLSessionDataTask` webservice methods.

After success response I am sending response to ViewController where actual request is triggered, but the thing is whenever I send a web request I am sending responseDelegate which contains my viewcontroller instance, after `NSURLSessionDataTask` my delegate becomes nil

```
//ViewController:<ResponseDelegate>

[[[WebServiceController alloc]init]sendWebServiceRequest:@"GET" withUrl:@"http://192.168.10.51/contacts.php" withParameters:nil withView:self];

//ResponseDelegate:

-(void)onWebserviceResponseSuccess:(NSString *)response;
```

Comment: Please provide some code of `sendWebServiceRequest`. It's unclear how do you store `responseDelegate` until request is finished.